# How to ask user permissions at the time of installation Outlook add-ins?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

> I have created an outlook add-in, in which i am reading mail and
>   moving it to a different folder, thereby categorizing it based on its
>   content. But, it is showing the alert message to the user (See image
>   for reference), which shows I probably need to ask for user
>   permissions. Is there any way to prevent this error from showing up,
>   like, probably asking for permissions at the **time of installation**?
>   (How?)

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked Help button? It could be helpful. And most likely this behavior is governed by a registry key, and you need to find which key it is.

Comment: thanku @kennyzx there is any way to resolve by programmatic(c#).

Comment: Check out the Redemption library: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are listed at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52

In short, it is either

1. Up to date Antivirus app if you can control the environment
2. Utility like ClickYes
3. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author)